# iOS NativeControls - showToolBarTitle() is not working (PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, cordova, native, toolbar, phonegap-plugins

I just saw a post on the phonegap google group about the issue

[iOS NativeControls - showToolBarTitle() is not working.](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/2e8435270f7cf1d6/ed0cadc332299f05)

and have spent my last two days with searching a solution for this issue.

More specifically - I want to add a native iOS toolbar to my phonegap app with the following features:

- Title at the middle (I prefer an image, but a simple String in white color is also fine).
- Back button (at the left side).
- Action button (at the right side).
- Background color - I want to control the backgroud color of the toolbar (I want it to be green!)

Can you please help me in anyway to complete this tasks?

Do you have some partial working code like NativeControls toolbar?

P.S - I already implemented a tabbar with the NativeControls plugin.

Tnx! 
Lior.

Comment: Can you post your code or the project files for the NativeControls plugin. I've done everything but still not getting any tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have rewritten nativecontrols plugin for cordova 3.0. I see this question is a *little outdated*, but probably someone would want to use this plugin. actionsheet and toolbar is working now, tabbar and navbar is WIP.

https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.nativecontrols

BTW, in original repository toolbar is never works.

Comment: have you implemented a plugin which makes the toolbar function properly? it is not clear from your answer. Please rephrase to clarify it

Comment: yes, toolbar is working now (at least, adding items and handling tap on item).